# A 15-minute Cryptic

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

A hastily-made festive gift for PSE, and a test to see whether it is ever possible to make a puzzle faster than it takes someone here to solve it! :P

[image]

**Clues:**
1A  One of us in gold-coated regret
4A  Mixing up dictionary with basic directions is more mature?
5A  Stop, particularly, watery spirit

1D  Naturally produced zombie sound
2D  Aussie rockband toured Germany but lost direction, order
3D  Mixing up flora isn't beating around the bush!

Comment: Does 1D have two legitimate answers that does not affect the rest of the answers on the grid since one letter is different or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> 1A GUILT = U(-s) in [GILT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gilt) (here, '*one of us*' clues *one letter of US*)
>  4A OLDER = ([OED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary) + L + R)* (here, 'L' and 'R' are 'basic directions', i.e. left and right)
>  5A [NIXIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neck_(water_spirit)) = [NIX](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nix) + [IE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/i.e.)
>
>  1D GROWN = ddef of sorts (GROWN vs the soundalike GROAN), although ‘sound’ in the clue is doing double duty here...
>  2D INDEX = [INX(-s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INXS) around DE (the '*lost direction*' here is the removal of 'S' for 'South'; DE is the abbreviation for Germany)
>  3D TERSE = TREES*

Comment: Nice one, I was not sure whether it was groan or grown.

Comment: @Smartest1here I've gone with GROWN because I *think* the OP wants it to sound like the 'zombie sound' (GROAN). However, this requires using 'sound' in two different ways at once, which isn't standard in a cryptic clue. So it's a bit of a coin flip on that one I guess! :)

Comment: What is your strategy doing these I was stuck!

Comment: @Smartest1here Just a case of examining clues in turn until something clicks! First I solved 1D and 4A ('more mature' was a likely definition with an obvious 5-letter answer - then fit the wordplay to it), 2D followed thanks to music and geography knowledge and the now-known middle letter, 5A I then figured began with NIX (N_X known and 'stop'), a little googling gave the complete word, 1A fell next, and finally 3D (embarrassingly - that should have been the easiest! I had TERSE for a long time but couldn't think of a *flower* that anagrammed to it - turns out there was an easier word!).

Comment: It might be worth saying that rot13("vaqverpg nantenzf") as in 4A and 3D are generally frowned upon in cryptic crosswords. Though for a throwaway 5x5 a certain amount of latitude should be given :-).

Comment: I wouldn't give that sort of latitude - I think those, as well as 1D, are unfair.

Comment: The perils of 15min. Agreed that the double answer if 1D is a big flaw, and I have never really been sure about the fairness/unfairness of using the other trick. I see it done quite often and tbh I didn’t think it would take you all too long to undo it. >.> I can only offer apologies and accept the regift of helpful instruction :)