# A teeny cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

I promise, I had the [idea](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=56550034#56550034) for a 5x5 cryptic before [Graylocke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/106029/69582)!

[image: 5x5 crossword grid, with three evenly-spaced out 5-letter words going across and three going down]

**Clues:**
1A  Record side conversation. (5)
4A  Demand previous show. (5)
5A  Butcher lead-free paint. (5)

1D  Revolutionary invention is "essential to law", he elaborated. (5)
2D  Country's capital**s**?? Of interest, take a look, yeah. (5)
3D  Weekly repetition (Rent! Rent!) provides a key, perhaps. (5)

This is my first "full" cryptic crossword (and my first cryptic puzzle that I didn't have someone else check first!), and I'd appreciate feedback on my cluing.

Comment: Copycat! Just joking :P

Comment: Not only were you planning it first, you executed it better :)

Comment: Related: [The smallest crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1725/5373)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grid:

> ```
> W R I T E
> H   T   N
> E X A C T
> E   L   E
> L A Y E R
> ```

Explanations:

> 1A. Homophone of RIGHT. 4A. EX + ACT. 5A. (-s)LAYER. 1D. Substring. 2D. Capitals = first letters. 3D. Repeated letter in WEEKLY plus RENT*.

Feedback on cluing, as requested:

> 1A. I'd prefer something like "*in* conversation". 4A. Nice one: perfectly sound wordplay and good surface. 5A. Wordplay is good, surface reads a bit oddly (but perfectly OK overall). 1D. Fine. 2D. I'm not a fan of "capitals" to mean "initial letters" when the letters in question aren't actually capitalized :-). 3D. I'd lose the ", perhaps" at the end, I think. Surface is a little clumsy either way. Not terribly keen on "X repetition" to mean "thing repeated in X" but I don't think it's *unsound*.

Comment: Not only did I get sniped, but I got sniped doubly!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because hexomino didn't have the explanation for 5A upon posting.

Comment: Also, I was quicker :-). (By, literally, seconds.)

Comment: I need to write less (or quicker). Well done!

Answer (score 5):

The solved crossword

> [image]

Clue explanations

> 1A WRITE sounds like (conversation) RIGHT (side) and Record is the definition
>  4A EXACT (demand) = EX (previous) ACT (show)
>  5A SLAYER (butcher) without the lead letter and "paint" is the def.
>  1D Revolutionary invention is the def and it's essential to laW HE ELaborated.
>  2D **I**nterest **t**ake **a** **l**ook **y**eah
>  3D W**ee**kly repetition clues E, "Rent! Rent!" means Rent, anagrammed (NTER) "provides a key, perhaps" is the definition.